# StrongLoop API Explorer returning an error

Tags: javascript, api, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have just tried to use the StrongLoop API Explorer as explained on  http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Use+API+Explorer; I have followed all the steps indicated in the document starting from downloading the sample code from https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-explorer.

When I hit "Try it out" I keep getting a JS error (from firebug)

```
TypeError: this.type.split is not a function
http://localhost:3000/explorer/lib/shred.bundle.js
Line 2034
```

and the following is the response body that I keep getting

```
{
    "error": {
"name": "ValidationError",
"status": 422,
"message": "The `Person` instance is not valid. Details: `FirstName` can't be blank; `LastName` can't be blank; `Age` can't be blank; `DOB` can't be blank.",
"statusCode": 422,
"details": {
  "context": "Person",
  "codes": {
    "FirstName": [
      "presence"
    ],
    "LastName": [
      "presence"
    ],
    "Age": [
      "presence"
    ],
    "DOB": [
      "presence"
    ]
  },
  "messages": {
    "FirstName": [
      "can't be blank"
    ],
    "LastName": [
      "can't be blank"
    ],
    "Age": [
      "can't be blank"
    ],
    "DOB": [
      "can't be blank"
    ]
  }
},
"stack": "ValidationError: The `Person` instance is not valid. Details: `FirstName` can't be blank; `LastName` can't be blank; `Age` can't be blank; `DOB` can't be blank.\n    at D:\\explorerAPI\\node_modules\\loopback-datasource-juggler\\lib\\dao.js:156:16\n    at ModelConstructor.<anonymous> (D:\\explorerAPI\\node_modules\\loopback-datasource-juggler\\lib\\validations.js:453:11)\n    at ModelConstructor.next (D:\\explorerAPI\\node_modules\\loopback-datasource-juggler\\lib\\hooks.js:66:12)\n    at ModelConstructor.<anonymous> (D:\\explorerAPI\\node_modules\\loopback-datasource-juggler\\lib\\validations.js:450:23)\n    at ModelConstructor.trigger (D:\\explorerAPI\\node_modules\\loopback-datasource-juggler\\lib\\hooks.js:56:12)\n    at ModelConstructor.Validatable.isValid (D:\\explorerAPI\\node_modules\\loopback-datasource-juggler\\lib\\validations.js:430:8)\n    at Function.DataAccessObject.create (D:\\explorerAPI\\node_modules\\loopback-datasource-juggler\\lib\\dao.js:152:7)\n    at SharedMethod.invoke (D:\\explorerAPI\\node_modules\\loopback\\node_modules\\strong-remoting\\lib\\shared-method.js:207:17)\n    at HttpContext.invoke (D:\\explorerAPI\\node_modules\\loopback\\node_modules\\strong-remoting\\lib\\http-context.js:243:12)\n    at D:\\explorerAPI\\node_modules\\loopback\\node_modules\\strong-remoting\\lib\\remote-objects.js:475:9"
```

}
}

Any help in fixing this would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is a regression caused by https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-js/issues/107. And we're working on a workaround at: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-explorer/pull/29. It should be merged soon.